# Get webforms data asynchronous?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

I've got some dashboard web forms that ask for some selection data upon opening them. Something like "from customer, to customer, etc" Then on the confirm button they do launch the data retrieval and show the results in a gridview. Those queries are time consuming ones and return a huge amount of data.

They execute the data fetch in a separate delegate so it can avoid session timeout, for example.
Now I'm asked for something more elegant and I'm not sure of what it's the best approach to solve this.

Basically what the form does it's:
You fill the filters then push a button.
On the button.click, it has to **show a waiting dialog.**
Execute a DB method that returns a Datatable
Puts it into session (grids requeriment, doh!)
Set the datasource for the grid on that session object and databind it.
**Hide the wait dialog.**

I've tried so far:
PageAsyncTask: does not return ui control. Perhaps did something wrong.
System.Threading.Tasks: Too many problems with session and UI context that made me impossible to return the data.

I'm running asp.net 4.0 and vb. It would be nice to go async, but for now I'm stuck with .net 4.0

Comment: So the main problem is to show waiting dialog for the duration of long postback?

Comment: @Yuriy I already have a custom control that shows a waiting dialog. the problem it's showing it, or btter hiding it. The .ContinueWith functionality of Threading.Tasks, for example, executed in a separate web context so It can't hide the dialog. (FromCurrentSynchronizationContext option made it to not execute) Also I wasn't able to get the dt I stored in session object at the Main task. Passed session through param and dt had data but was always lost at some place.

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't u simple use client-side JavaScript to show the waiting dialog (on setTimeout from Button's ClientClick) and then just let postback take its course? When page posts back - the dialog will be hidden automatically. No need to mess with threads or async and such.

Comment: We use session timeouts of 5mins. The page itself has a hidden control that manages the stay alive, and also manages unique pages id's so the user can work on the same object from several tabs without collisions. The fact it's that the data mining can be up to 30mins and that time the session controls would be inactive, so the page would be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the form in a UpdatePanel and add an ASP [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control to the page, then put the gridview in a second UpdatePanel that gets updated from the form action. UpdatePanel allows for asynchronous (well, partial postback) operations on Webforms, and the UpdateProgress control will then display a "loading" message or something similar. Something like the code below will put a spinning loading icon in front of your text.

```
         <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="upUpdateProgress">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:0.60; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: fixed; height: 100%;">
                    <div style="margin:auto;font-family:Trebuchet MS;filter: alpha(opacity=100);opacity: 1;
                        font-size:small;vertical-align: middle;top: 45%;position: fixed;right: 45%;color: #275721;text-align: center;background-color: White;
                              height: 100px;
                              ">
                        <img src="Images/loading-icon.gif" alt="Loading. Please Wait."/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm dropping updatepanels and viewstate in my solution. In fact, the grid doesn't allow to be inside updatepanel for export functionality to work. BTW, the progress dialog control I made is something simmilar to what you showed there, and can be hooked to some buttons click. But the effect there is that it shows, but it's frozen.

Comment: Will session expire during that updatepanel callback using the updateprogress?